# Twitter-Bootstrap typeahead not working

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm having some trouble getting the typeahead working in Bootstrap, and I've boiled the problem down to this short example. (I'm new to Bootstrap.) When I type in the input, no typeahead suggestions appear. Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <label for="primaryCustName">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="['Bob','Jim','Sue']" class="form-control" id="primaryCustName">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: typeahead is not a complement of bootstrap, show your script, something should be wrong there

Comment: It doesn't look like you are including the typeahead js file? It isn't included in Bootstrap.

Comment: @joshhunt, Hmm, this page says it is included. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead  . At the top it says it's in the .js files.

Comment: Looks like it is included in v2 but not v3. See https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ and https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead which should help you out.

Comment: @joshhunt, yep. I just search my minified code and it's not there. Wonder why they took it out. I'll add the script. That ought to get it. Thanks.

Comment: According to that github link they dropped it "in favor of folks using Twitter's typeahead. Twitter's typeahead has more features than the old bootstrap-typeahead.js and less bugs."

Comment: @joshhunt: Good info. Would you mind putting that in an answer. I'll select it. It might help some other lost souls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typeahead function was removed from Bootstrap in v3. According to @mdo it was dropped "in favor of folks using Twitter's typeahead. Twitter's typeahead has more features than the old bootstrap-typeahead.js and less bugs."

Your two options from here are:

1. Use a port of Bootstrap v2 Typeahead, you can find one [here](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead).
2. Use Twitter Typeahead which can be found [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).